# How do I get core clojure functions to work with my defrecords

Tags: clojure, protocols, frequency, census

I have a defrecord called a bag.  It behaves like a list of item to count.  This is sometimes called a frequency or a census.  I want to be able to do the following

```
(def b (bag/create [:k 1 :k2 3])  
(keys bag)
=> (:k :k1)
```

I tried the following:

```
(defrecord MapBag [state]                                                                                                                                         
  Bag                                                                                                                                                             
   (put-n [self item n]                                                                                                                                          
     (let [new-n (+ n (count self item))]                                                                                                                        
          (MapBag. (assoc state item new-n))))                                                                                                                      

  ;... some stuff

  java.util.Map                                                                                                                                                   
    (getKeys [self] (keys state)) ;TODO TEST                                                                                                                      

  Object                                                                                                                                                          
   (toString [self]                                                                                                                                              
     (str ("Bag: " (:state self)))))
```

When I try to require it in a repl I get:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate interface name in class file compile__stub/techne/bag/MapBag (bag.clj:12)
```

What is going on?  How do I get a keys function on my bag?  Also am I going about this the correct way by assuming clojure's keys function eventually calls getKeys on the map that is its argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defrecord automatically makes sure that any record it defines participates in the ipersistentmap interface.  So you can call keys on it without doing **anything.**

So you can define a record, and instantiate and call keys like this:

```
user> (defrecord rec [k1 k2])
user.rec
user> (def a-rec (rec. 1 2))
#'user/a-rec
user> (keys a-rec)
(:k1 :k2)
```

Your error message indicates that one of your declarations is duplicating an interface that defrecord gives you for free.  I think it might actually be both.

Is there some reason why you cant just use a plain vanilla map for your purposes?  With clojure, you often want to use plain vanilla data structures when you can.

Edit: if for whatever reason you don't want the ipersistentmap included, look into deftype.

Comment: interesting.  Thank you.  There is a reason for this to not be a vanilla map.  If I have a census of people living on planets: I might want something like: (get planets earth) => 8billion, (get planets mars) => 0.  A vanilla map will give me nil people on mars, unless I use (get planets mars 0).  I don't want the client to have to know that.

Answer (score 3):

Rob's answer is of course correct; I'm posting this one in response to the OP's comment on it -- perhaps it might be helpful in implementing the required functionality with `deftype`.

I have once written an implementation of a "default map" for Clojure, which acts just like a regular map except it returns a fixed default value when asked about a key not present inside it. The code is in [this Gist](http://gist.github.com/468332).

I'm not sure if it will suit your use case directly, although you can use it to do things like

```
user> (:earth (assoc (DefaultMap. 0 {}) :earth 8000000000))
8000000000
user> (:mars (assoc (DefaultMap. 0 {}) :earth 8000000000))
0
```

More importantly, it should give you an idea of what's involved in writing this sort of thing with `deftype`.

Then again, it's based on `clojure.core/emit-defrecord`, so you might look at that part of Clojure's sources instead... It's doing a lot of things which you won't have to (because it's a function for preparing macro expansions -- there's lots of syntax-quoting and the like inside it which you have to strip away from it to use the code directly), but it is certainly the highest quality source of information possible. [Here](http://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/1.2.0/src/clj/clojure/core_deftype.clj#L134)'s a direct link to that point in the source for the 1.2.0 release of Clojure.

*Update:*

One more thing I realised might be important. If you rely on a special map-like type for implementing this sort of thing, the client might `merge` it into a regular map and lose the "defaulting" functionality (and indeed any other special functionality) in the process. As long as the "map-likeness" illusion maintained by your type is complete enough for it to be used as a regular map, passed to Clojure's standard function etc., I think there might not be a way around that.

So, at some level the client will probably have to know that there's some "magic" involved; if they get correct answers to queries like `(:mars {...})` (with no `:mars` in the `{...}`), they'll have to remember not to `merge` this into a regular map (`merge`-ing the other way around would work fine).